# How to get Obfuscated Build(Smart Assembly 5) into Drop Folder(TFS 2010)

Tags: vb.net, smartassembly

I've been tasked with obfuscating and auto building our projects. I have the two working great independant of one another, but I need to find a way to get the obfuscated build into the drop folder set in TFS2010.

In my .vbproj file my MSBuild code looks like this:

`<PropertyGroup>
<PostBuildEvent>"C:\Program Files\Red Gate\SmartAssembly 5\smartassembly.com" /build "$(ProjectDir)DBManager.saproj" /markasreleased </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>`

The problem is it's building the unobfuscated code and putting it into the drop folder. 
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Larry B.

Comment: Did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 1):

I usually perform obfuscation after all compilation is complete.  I then will have a subfolder of the drop folder (i.e. *DropFolderPath*\Obfuscated) and output each one after running my obfuscation utility into that subfolder.  That allows the team to have both the unobfuscated assemblies and a copy of the obfuscated assemblies.

I also do it outside of MSBuild.  I use *InvokeProcess* workflow activities in the broader Windows Workflow Foundation-based build processt template.

EDIT:  I actually put together a blog post for how to integrate SmartAssembly into the TFS Build process here:  http://bit.ly/SmartAssemblyTFS